# how to conditionally deploy config maps from helm charts from directory

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'd like to conditionally deploy configmaps from a helm chart. i.e.;

- deploy dev only when env in values.yaml == dev
- stage only when env in values.yaml == stage
- prod only when env in values.yaml = prod
- all-environments when env in values.yaml == all-environments

What is the cleanest way to do this?

This is my folder hierarchy.

```
kube-prometheus-stack
  charts
    grafana
        env
          dev
            dashboard1-cm.yaml
            dashboard2-cm.yaml
            etc
          staging
          prod
          all-environments
```